# Owl Carousel not displaying images on Android Browser - Poss CSS rule issue

Tags: android, css, image, owl-carousel

I have an Owl Carousel V2 and images (PNG or JPG) are not displaying on my oldish HTC phone, Android 4.2, it fails on the Android Browser V4.2.2, but works on Chrome, same device

It works fine on 3 x browsers on my Mac, 3 x browsers Win 10 and XP, iPhone, iPad and Android tablet.

I have a CSS class to scale the images - when I remove this it works.

```
   <div class="carousel_wrapper">
    <div id="samewidth_images" class="owl-carousel">

        <div>
          <img class='a4_diary_image' src='sizes/A4_test.jpg'>
          <div class='owl_diary_desc'>
            A4 diaries 
          </div>
        </div>

        <div>
          <img class='quarto_diary_image' src='sizes/Q_test.jpg'>
          <div class='owl_diary_desc'>
            Quarto diaries
          </div>
        </div>

        <div>
          <img class='a5_diary_image' src='sizes/A5_test.jpg'>
          <div class='owl_diary_desc'>
            A5 diaries - executive and standard

          </div>
        </div>

        <div>
          <img class='a6_diary_image' src='sizes/A6_test.jpg'>
          <div class='owl_diary_desc'>
            A6 diaries - new for 2017
          </div>
        </div>

        <div>
          <img class='pocket_diary_image' src='sizes/POCKET_test.jpg?a=v'>
          <div class='owl_diary_desc'>
            Pocket diaries
          </div>
        </div>
```

Sample of the CSS, which if I remove the image appears.

```
.a5_diary_image {
  max-width: 70%;
  max-height: 70%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}


.a6_diary_image {
  max-width: 50%;
  max-height: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

The carousel seems to be initialising OK as the text is there and can be swipped.  Givin that is it android 4.2 I can't plus in a USB and inspect the DOM to try to determine the issue.  There is just nothing where the images should be, no X, and it's not taking up any whitespace.